# Which one will be faster in MySQL with BINARY or without Binary?

Tags: mysql

Please explain, which one will be faster in Mysql for the following query?

```
SELECT * FROM `userstatus` where BINARY Name = 'Raja'

[OR]

SELECT * FROM `userstatus` where Name = 'raja'
```

Db entry for Name field is 'Raja'

I have 10000 records in my db, i tried with "explain" query but both saying same execution time.

Comment: If your collation is case insensitive and **Name** is indexed then the second query should run faster, otherwise there should be no much difference.

Comment: In general, i have not indexed any field in my table and have more than 1000000 in mytable, then which would be the faster one!

Comment: Well... BINARY does not depend on collation, so without index this can run faster. In any case I think the best way is to try :)

Comment: use index for frequently used filter.

Comment: If you don't use indexes, then don't bother with `which is faster questions`, indexes are the single most important factor, everything else is micro-optimization. If you have 1 million rows, a `a='b'` search without index will take 500,000 lookups an average. With an index it will take 30 lookups max (29 on average). Four orders of magnitude difference.

Answer (score 3):

Your question does not make sense.

The collation of a row determines the layout of the index and whether tests wil be case-sensitive or not.
If you cast a row, the cast will take time.

So logically the uncasted operation should be faster....

However, if the cast makes it to find fewer rows than the casted operation will be faster or the other way round.
This of course changes the whole problem and makes the comparison invalid.

A cast to BINARY makes the comparison to be case-sensitive, changing the nature of the test and very probably the number of hits.

**My advice**
Never worry about speed of collations, the percentages are so small it is never worth bothering about.
The speed penalty from using `select *` (a big no no) will far outweigh the collation issues.
Start with putting in an index. That's a factor 10,000 speedup with a million rows.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `Names` field is a simple latin-1 text type, and there's no index on it, then the BINARY version of the query will be faster. By default, MySQL does case-insensitive comparisons, which means the field values and the value you're comparing against both get smashed into a single case (either all-upper or all-lower) and then compared. Doing a binary comparison skips the case conversion and does a raw 1:1 numeric comparison of each character value, making it a case-sensitive comparison.

Of course, that's just one very specific scenario, and it's unlikely to be met in your case. Too many other factors affect this, especially the presence of an index.